# malloc on struct containing unique_ptr

Tags: c++, malloc, unique-ptr

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int myInt;
    std::unique_ptr<Something> myUniquePtr;
}
```

What's wrong when `malloc()` is used to allocate memory (compared to using `new` I understand the `unique_ptr` constructor is not called). What does happen to `myUniquePtr`?

Let's say just after `malloc` I perform:

```
myUniquePtr = std::make_unique<Something>(...)
```

Is myUniquePtr a valid object?

What could be the consequences?

Comment: Why do you assume `myUniquePtr` would be properly initialized by `std::make_unique()`? That function doesn't operate on `myUniquePtr` it simply returns a value to be copied/moved into it.

Comment: All `malloc` does is allocate a bunch of bytes.  It does not create objects.  Casting the return value of `malloc` (which I assume you are doing) does *not* turn those bytes into the object you are using.  All it does is fool the compiler into believing the object is valid, when it isn't valid.

Comment: "What's wrong when malloc() is used"? Answer: "the unique_ptr constructor is not called". "What does happen to myUniquePtr?" It is never set up correctly. "I assume myUniquePtr is then properly initialized through std::make_unique" Absolutely not.  std::make_unique is never used in your code and even if it were, myUniquePtr was never set up correctly, so can't be expected to act properly when it is assigned the result of make_unique.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++. malloc will not call constructors and you will not get objects in a valid state. Note after C++11 came out even new/delete are no longer recommended. Unique pointers should be created using std::make_unique.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding around how objects work in C++ vs. references in something like C# or Java. Assigning to something in C++ modifies that thing, it doesn't "point" it to a new object unless the type is a plain old pointer (in which case it still modifies the pointer's value, i.e., the address it's pointing to).

Comment: That is also why using `malloc` to create objects requires you to tell C++ that the `malloc` actually refers to an object.  You do that by using `placement-new` along with the `malloc` call.

Comment: @AviBerger 1st post edited

Comment: if you must use malloc for some reason, then use 'placement new' next, this will complete the initialization of the allocated memory

Comment: That calls myUniquePtr's assignment operator which requires that myUniquePtr is a valid, properly setup object. It isn't. Boom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is a class type.  `malloc()` only allocates raw memory, it does not call any class constructors within that memory.  Thus, `myUniquePtr` will not be initialized correctly, and so cannot be used for *anything* meaningful since it is not a valid object.  It can't be read from.  It can't be assigned to.  Nothing.

If you use `malloc()` (or any other non-C++ allocator) to allocate memory for an object, you **must** use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) afterwards to ensure the object is actually initialized properly in that memory before you can then use the object, eg:

```
void *memory = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
MyStruct *pMyStruct = new(memory) MyStruct;
...
pMyStruct->~MyStruct();
free(memory);
```

Comment: Even after `make_unique` has been called?

Comment: If you have an improperly configured object and then assign to it, you likely screwed. Consider the case of `std::string`. If you `bad_string = "Hello world!";`, Crom only knows where `bad_string`'s pointers are pointing and where in memory it will try to write "Hello world!".

Comment: @floflo29 Yes. `make_unique()` will return a new `unique_ptr` that it constructed. If you simply `malloc()` the struct, you would be moving that new `unique_ptr` into an invalid `unique_ptr`. The target `unique_ptr` must be a valid object before it can be moved into from another object.

Comment: In the case of assigning to `unique_ptr`, the `unique_ptr` needs to properly dispose of the object it currently owns before it can be reassigned. If that currently owned object is bogus... Ka-BOOM!